Which CSOM SDK from NuGet gallery has to be used with SharePoint Server SE Subscription Edition
We are migrating from SharePoint server 2016 to SharePoint SE.
I could not find any CSOM in NuGet gallery specifically for SE. There are 2 - one for 2016 and one for 2019. which one should i use
https://www.nuget.org/PACKAGES?q=SharePoint+Client&frameworks=netframework&includeComputedFrameworks=true&frameworkFilterMode=all&prerel=true&sortby=relevance

SharePoint Server Subscription Edition (SE) is essentially the latest iteration following SharePoint 2019. Therefore, for client-side object model (CSOM) libraries, you should use the CSOM package for SharePoint 2019, as it is the most recent and compatible with SharePoint SE.
This CSOM package will allow you to interact with SharePoint SE effectively. If you run into specific issues or need functionality that seems to be missing, it is always worthwhile to check the official Microsoft documentation or forums for any updates or additional guidance specific to SharePoint SE.

You can use the 2019 version. But it doesn't contain all updated CSOM methods for SE. You can also copy the client DLL's from your SharePoint SE hive and create a package yourself.
